# How to do something after x times in PHP?

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop

I'm just a beginner in php and need some help.

I would like to output an array which contains an ID, name and an URL as example.

The array is declared as $data_array

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="item">$ID $name $URL</div>
  <div class="item">$ID $name $URL</div>
  <div class="item">$ID $name $URL</div>
  <div class="item">$ID $name $URL</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="item">$ID $name $URL</div>
  <div class="item">$ID $name $URL</div>
  <div class="item">$ID $name $URL</div>
  <div class="item">$ID $name $URL</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="item">$ID $name $URL</div>
  <div class="item">$ID $name $URL</div>
</div>
```

So how can I do it, that after the 4th item the DIV is closed and if there more than 4, or 8 or 12 and so on a new row begins. And how to get it, if it is like in the example, in the last row only 2 or 1 or 3 items, that it will be closed?

Thanks!

Comment: keep a counter, e.g. `$row++`, and test it with `if` and a modulo: `if ($row % 4 == 0) { you're on a multiple-of-4-row }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-chunk.php) to split your list into chunks of 4.

```
foreach (array_chunk($list, 4) as $row) {
    echo '<div class="row">';
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        echo '<div class="item">';
        echo $id;
        echo '</div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```